# Загрузить HTML из файла в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Я использую Angular.JS
В одном из сервисов, который используется для построения уведомлений, у меня есть следующий шаблон:

```
var template = '<div data-notify="container" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-4 alert alert-{0}" role="alert">....
```

Как можно загрузить данный шаблон из внешнего файла для того, чтобы разделить HTML и JS? 
Чтобы использовать что-то наподобие этого:

```
var template = loader.load('/notificationTemplate.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `templateUrl`:

```
templateUrl: '/notificationTemplate.html'
```

Comment: не вариант, изменил описание

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял,попробуйте просто создать директиву и использовать ее в html.

```
<my-block></my-block>
```

Это вы пишите туда,где должна быть та часть кода,которую вам надо загрузить.
Создайте папку с названиям template и киньте туда тот html,который вам надо загрузить под названием "myBlock.html".
Потом в js пишите:

```
app.directive("myBlock",function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl : 'template/myBlock.html'
    }
});
```